# Catch strings between double quotes in a text and map their indexes into array, C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, substring, double-quotes

I have a string:

```
string text1 = "Lorem \"ipsum dolor\" quisque at \"massa non erat\". Donec auctor \"blandit\" nibh!";
```

I am looking for any solution that:

1) catches  all words between the double quotes and,

2) assigns them a value of 10 so:

```
int[] result = {0,10,10,0,0,10,10,10,0,0,10,0}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please share what you have attempted so far.

Comment: If you haven't tried anything, here's an idea. Split the string on _space_. Then check of double quotes in each of the resultant strings, if present then insert **10**, else **0** into an array of int

Comment: That's not hard algorithmic problem, try to do it by yourself.

Comment: What is `text1 = { Lorem "ipsum dolor" quisque at "massa non erat". Donec auctor "blandit" nibh! }`? That's not valid C#.

Comment: text1 is a string = "Lorem "ipsum dolor" ....

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var text1 = "Lorem \"ipsum dolor\" quisque at \"massa non erat\". Donec auctor \"blandit\" nibh!";

var output =
    text1
        .Split('"')
        .SelectMany((x, n) => x.Trim().Split(' ').Select(y => n % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 10))
        .ToArray();
```

It produces `int[] result = new [] { 0, 10, 10, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0 }`.

That's not exactly what you're after, but the fact that there's a `.` after the second set of double quotes makes this code think that `.` is a valid word. You might need to think about how to clean up that string first.

Comment: It seems to me that code doesn't work in case text starts with double quote.

Comment: @Enigmativity    How about:  var text1 = "\"Lorem ipsum dolor\" quisque at \"massa non erat\". Donec auctor \"blandit\" nibh!";

Comment: @ZasypinN.V. - The OP only asked about that specific string, but putting a `.Where(y => y != "")` after the second `.Split(...)` may be a sufficient fix for the OP.

Comment: @ArtJ - Please see my comment to Zasypin re an initial quote fix.

Comment: @ZasypinN.V.  If var text1 = "\"Lorem ipsum dolor\" quisque at \"massa non erat\". Donec auctor \"blandit nibh!\"";  and .Where(y => y != ""), it gives me one more 0 element just before \"blandit nibh!\"

Comment: @ArtJ As wrote Enigmativity `but the fact that there's a . after the second set of double quotes makes this code think that . is a valid word`, `.` in `. Donec auctor` gives you additional 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to achieve this easily. But if you want a deeper understanding of how to do this and want your code to be more easily interpretable and editable, I suggest you use the following code:

```
        string text1 = @"Lorem ""ipsum dolor"" quisque at ""massa non erat"".Donec auctor ""blandit"" nibh!";
        text1 = text1.Replace("."," ");
        string[] splitted = text1.Split(' ');
        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        bool alreadystarted = false;
        foreach (string element in splitted)
        {
            if (element.Contains("\""))
            {
                if (alreadystarted == false)
                {
                    if (element.Count(f => f == '"') != 2)
                    {
                        alreadystarted = true;
                    }
                    result.Add(10);
                }
                else
                {
                    alreadystarted = false;
                    result.Add(10);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (alreadystarted == true)
                {
                    result.Add(10);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Add(0);
                }
            }
        }
```

The int results are:

> 0, 10, 10, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0

Answer (score 0):

Check this program

```
var data = "Lorem \"ipsum dolor\" quisque at \"massa non erat\" . Donec auctor \"blandit\" nibh!";
        var arrayText = data.Split(' ');
        int[] result = new int[arrayText.Length];
        var i = 0;
        var doublequotebits = false;
        foreach (var value in arrayText)
        {
            if (value.StartsWith("\"") && value != ".")
                doublequotebits = true;

            if (doublequotebits)
                result[i] = 10;

            i++;

            if (value.EndsWith("\""))
                doublequotebits = false;
        }
```